# Atom hydrogen on windows 10: No kernels installed

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

I am using Atom on windows 10 and I have the issue that hydrogen isn't running or updating any kernels while stating the error message:

[Atom hydrogen Error: No kernels Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9Tz.png)

I have python 3.8.4 installed as well as ipython 7.16.1
I can run python scripts from atom, code highlighting ect.. works just fine. Jupyter Notebook is installed and works too when run from the command shell.
Ipython is working too in the command shell. Any suggestions what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

So this one resolved the issue for me:

-Make sure pip and jupyter are updated to the newest release.

-go to your windows command prompt (press WIN+R, then type cmd and press ENTER)
then try entering the following:

```
python -m ipkernel install --user
pip install --upgrade ipkernel
```

Then go into Atom and select Packages -> Hydrogen -> Update Kernels